# Profile Photo Dimensions Limit

Tags: chatter, profile

I have a user attempting to upload a JPG that is less than 2MB (well within the [8MB limit](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=collab_profile_photo.htm&language=en_US)) as a profile photo, but receives an error:

```
Error: The photo's dimensions are too large.
```

I've been able to reproduce this with my admin user, so it isn't a fluke. I can't seem to locate any documentation around restrictions on photo dimensions, does anyone know what the limits are? The dimensions on the photo in question are 5616x3744 pixels.

[image]

Comment: He should really resize the photo regardless. Stop and think about it how many pixels that is compared to your monitor (1200x800 typical new laptop), let alone the size his profile pic is going to be viewed at. THAT is the real issue. What's happened is he's heavily compressed it using JPEG far beyond what SF ever anticipated when the 8MB limit was set. 7 or 8 years ago, very few people could open an image of this size on a PC.

Comment: I don't disagree, but with community users there is less governance going on with what people upload for profile photos (particularly when there is no warning about dimension size).

Comment: Notice that the error message says `The photo's dimensions are too large`. It doesn't say the file size is too large. That truly is the problem. SF can't resize a file with that many pixels in it. I don't recall what the exact number of pixels it is that are used in a profile pic, but it's something in the range of 120x160 or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Chatter REST API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/chatterapi/index_Left.htm#CSHID=quickreference_update_crop_user_photo.htm%7CStartTopic=Content%2Fquickreference_update_crop_user_photo.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp), the crop size for a profile photo is 120 pixels and the file size must be less than 2 MB. I also found this KB article: [Recommended Resolution Size for Profile / Group photos](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000176170&language=en_US) which recommended uploaded files be no larger than 200x200 pixels.

Comment: Salesforce support referenced the same Knowledge Article when I asked them about it rather than providing explicit dimensions, so I will point users towards this recommendation. Thanks!